# Mostrar App con pantalla bloqueada

Tags: android, firebase, swift

Es posible mostrar alguna pestaña de mi aplicación cuando la pantalla está bloqueada?, algo parecido a la visualización del panel de control de música cuando la pantalla sigue bloqueada...

Quiero mostrar el cambio de unos números en tiempo real, pero no sé si es posible mostrarlos mientras la pantalla está bloqueada. Quiero hacer esto sin necesidad de usar notificaciones.

Espero puedan ayudarme, 
desde ya,
muchas gracias!

Comment: Usualmente se añade una notificacion que permanezca activada no solo para que se vea la informacion cuando la app esta bloqueada, sino tambien para que el usuario pueda ver esos numeros cuando la app esta cerrada y evita que mueran tus servicios

Comment: necesitas hacer un widget con un layout para el lock screen, y en el xml del widget agrega: android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" (para lock y home screen). Aquí un tutorial: https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/content/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-2-app-widgets/2-1-c-app-widgets/2-1-c-app-widgets.html